# Change overlaid text of an outline header?

Tags: latex, auctex, overlays, outline-mode

**Q:** how do I add a new outline header regexp but change the overlaid text?

I often write presentations with [Beamer](https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/wiki/Home) in LaTeX.  As such, there are a *lot* of `frame` (ie, "slide") environments:

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{My frame}
  % ...
  % ...
\end{frame}
```

To make navigation easier, I've added the `frame` environment to `TeX-outline-extra` so that Emacs will treat frames as headers and allow me to hide and show them:

```
(add-to-list 'TeX-outline-extra '("\\\\begin{frame}" 5)) % at paragraph level
```

Now, when the headers are closed, I have the following:

```
\begin{frame}...
\begin{frame}...
\begin{frame}...
\begin{frame}...
```

That's a big help, but I'd like to have a visual cue about what each frame contains (such as the `frametitle`).  How could I get the following:

```
\begin{frame} (My frame)...
\begin{frame} (Another frame)...
\begin{frame} (A different frame)...
\begin{frame} (Yet another frame)...
```

Comment: In recent versions of beamer the frame title can be given as an env parameter: `\begin{frame}{My frame}`.

Comment: @JeanPierre: you're quite right, I never realized that.  Although it doesn't answer the original abstract question I asked, it does resolve the specific problem I needed to address.  If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it (after modifying the question scope accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot comment to the question..

Using JeanPierre's approach of creating frames and its titles, that is `\begin{frame}{some title}`, the solution is adding the following to `.emacs` or run it when needed..

```
(setq TeX-outline-extra '(("\\\\begin{frame}[{\[].+" 5)))
```

This is also the answer to the question that I posted [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/40589/how-to-hide-frame-environment-in-outline-minor-mode/43784#43784)