# How to hide frame environment in outline minor mode?

Tags: latex, auctex, beamer, outline-mode

I am using AUCTex and outline-minor-mode to produce Latex presentations with beamer. I wonder how I could tell the outline-minor-mode to hide the content of a frame.  I am not into LISP by now, so this [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19230/how-to-hide-targets) here might already give a hint to the answer, but I don't know how.

So my question is, how can I get outline-minor-mode -- may be even with a shortcut -- to change

```
\begin{frame}{frametitle_A}
   a lot of cool stuff
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{frametitle_B}
   a lot of other cool stuff
\end{frame}
```

into

```
\begin{frame}{frametitle_A}...

\begin{frame}{frametitle_B}...
```

and vice versa?
S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after doing quite some research I found this [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3072/how-to-use-auctex-and-outline-minor-mode-together-for-folding) and this [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OutlineMode#toc2) and finally this [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17658/change-overlaid-text-of-an-outline-header), which is basically asking for what I am looking for. I found the solution puzzle piece in the AUCTeX [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Outline.html#Outline). The solution is adding the following to `.emacs`

```
(setq TeX-outline-extra '(("\\\\begin{frame}[{\[].+" 5)))
```

The regular expression should match `\begin{frame}{some title}` and `\begin{frame}[some options]{another title}` in a beamer LaTeX file.